# Javascript promise issue

Tags: javascript, promise

I am uploading an image using `drag n drop` and cropping it using `croppie` plugin. Also, in case if the user has selected the wrong image and wants to change it then there is a `browse again` button to switch back to `drag n drop` state.

Everything was working fine while I was doing this with jquery code. However, I am trying to refactor my code to use `Javascript Promise`, it just runs for the first time only.

Promise code:

```js
const dragDrop = (params, element) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $(element || '.drag-drop').on('dragover', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        }).on('dragleave', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        }).on('drop', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            let fileList = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
            let conditions = $.extend({}, {
                files: 1,
                fileSize: (1024 * 1024 * 5),
                type: ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"],
                extension: ["gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png"]
            }, (params || {}));

            if (fileList.length > conditions.files)
            {
                reject('Please choose only ' + conditions.files + ' file(s)');
            }
            else if (fileList[0].size > (conditions.fileSize))
            {
                reject('File to large.!<br>Allowed: ' + (conditions.fileSize) + 'MB');
            }
            else
            {
                if (fileList[0].type == '')
                {
                    let ext = (fileList[0].name).split('.');

                    if ($.inArray(ext[ext.length - 1], conditions.extension) < 0)
                    {
                        reject('File type not allowed');
                    }
                }
                else if ($.inArray(fileList[0].type, conditions.type) < 0)
                {
                    reject('File type not allowed');
                }
            }

            resolve(fileList);
        });
    })
};
```

Drag-Drop code:

```js
dragDrop().then((files) => {
    croppie({
        url: 'url to upload',
        data: {
            token: "user identification token string"
        }
    }, files);
}).catch((message) => {
    alert(message);
});
```

Croppie code:

```js
function croppie(ajax, files, croppie, el)
{
    // variables
    let $image = $((el.image !== undefined) ? el.image : 'div.js-image');
    let $button = $((el.button !== undefined) ? el.button : '.js-crop-button');
    let $dragDrop = $((el.dragDrop !== undefined) ? el.dragDrop : '.drag-drop');
    let $browseButton = $((el.browse !== undefined) ? el.browse : '.js-browse');

    $imageCrop = $image.croppie($.extend(true, {
        enableExif: true,
        enableOrientation: true,
        viewport: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            type: 'square'
        },
        boundary: {
            height: 500
        }
    }, croppie)).removeClass('d-none');

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event) => {
        $imageCrop.croppie('bind', {
            url: event.target.result
        });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);

    $image.parent().removeClass('d-none');
    $button.removeClass('d-none');
    $dragDrop.addClass('d-none');

    $('.js-rotate-left, .js-rotate-right').off('click').on('click', function (ev) {
        $imageCrop.croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('deg')));
    });

    $browseButton.off('click').on('click', function() {
        $image.croppie('destroy');
        $image.parent().addClass('d-none');
        $button.addClass('d-none');

        $dragDrop.removeClass('d-none');
    });

    $button.off('click').on('click', () => {
        $imageCrop.croppie('result', {
            type: 'canvas',
            size: 'viewport'
        }).then((response) => {
            ajaxRequest($.extend(true, {
                data: {
                    "image": response,
                },
                success: (data) => {
                    (data.success == true)
                        ? window.parent.location.reload()
                        : alert(data.message);
                }
            }, ajax));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You can only resolve/reject a promise once.

Comment: Ok, then how do I solve this issue..?

Comment: What was your thinking in refactoring for promise here?

Comment: Actually, this kind of functionality is being used on several pages in the application. So, instead of writing the common code, such as: validations, etc., over and over again, I created a separate function for it.

Comment: Perhaps just using a callback that gets called in `.on('drop'` would do what you need then

Comment: Ok, i'll try that. Thank you :)